# Angular - How to make results show, only if unchecked

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-filter

I have code that filters and shows the result of the box checked. When all the checkboxes are unchecked it shows all the results and when boxes are checked it only shows the boxes selected.

However, I'm trying to show all the results when the boxes are unchecked and if a check box is checked then it doesn't show that specific result, while continuing to show the boxes that are unchecked.

controller.js

```
function AdvisorListCtrl( $location, $scope, db) {

    $scope.orderProp = 'number';
    $scope.courseCheckboxes = {};
    $scope.teacherCheckboxes = {};
    $scope.courses = db.courses.query({order:$scope.orderProp, name:$scope.query});

    function getChecked(obj){
        var checked = [];
        for(var key in obj)
            if(obj[key]) checked.push(key);
        return checked;
    }

    $scope.searchFilter = function(row){
        var courChecked = getChecked($scope.courseCheckboxes);
        var teachChecked = getChecked($scope.teacherCheckboxes);
        if (courChecked.length == 0 && teachChecked.length == 0)
            return true;
        else {
            if ($scope.courseCheckboxes[row.name])
                return true;
            else {
                return row.teacher.split(/,\s*/).some(function(teach){
                    return $scope.teacherCheckboxes[teach];
                });
            }
        }

    }
}
```

html

```
<li><b><h2>Filter by Class</h2></b></li>
<li ng-repeat="course in courses | orderBy:['-status', 'name']">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="courseCheckboxes[course.name]" />{{course.name}}
    </label>
</li>
```

Comment: Without knowing what `courses` looks like and the `searchFilter` in user, it is difficult to say what you are trying to ask. If you could replicate your problem on this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/TdilRlUr0y5oDeoZIU22?p=preview it'll be much easier to find a solution for it.

Comment: Sorry. I was basing this off of this jsfiddle, something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/TheSharpieOne/ZebC7/ but instead of only showing the box thats checked. It would hide the box thats checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had misunderstood your question so I re-edited the answer.

When searchFilter(record) returns false the record is filtered out (and not displayed).

Here is a version of the filter that should do the opposite of what was doing (hide the checked merchants, and the merchants containing the checked brands). Hope this helps.

**html**

```
<div ng-repeat="record in records | filter: searchFilter">
{{record.Description}}
```

**js**

```
$scope.searchFilter = function(row){
  var mercChecked = getChecked($scope.merchantCheckboxes);
  var brandChecked = getChecked($scope.brandCheckboxes);
  if(mercChecked.length == 0 && brandChecked.length == 0)
    return true;
  else{
    if($scope.merchantCheckboxes[row.MerchantName]){
      return false;  // <----------------- changed here true to false
    } else {
      // changed here adding ! 
      return !row.BrandList.split(/,\s*/).some(function(brand){
        return $scope.brandCheckboxes[brand];
      });
    }
  }
};
```